# Toolbar Changes Color During Segue

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

I am currently working on making the register section of an iOS app in Swift 3.0.2.

[Here's a gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQZZJ.gif)
of the problem I am having. Watch the toolbar above the keyboard as the segue occurs. It flashes to a darker shade before it fully loads. This occurs whether or not the keyboard is active throughout the process (ViewController has toolbar as inputAccessoryView).

Here is the toolbar implementation (it's the same for each View).

```
fileprivate let toolbar = { () -> UIToolbar in
    let toolbar = UIToolbar()
    toolbar.barStyle = .default
    toolbar.isTranslucent = true
    toolbar.tintColor = UIColor(netHex: Constant.Color.darkerCrimsonColor)
    toolbar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    toolbar.sizeToFit()
    return toolbar
}()

override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
    return toolbar
}

fileprivate func setupToolbar() {
    let otherButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Next", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.done, target: self, action: #selector(nextViewController))
    toolBar.setItems([otherButton, otherButton, doneButton], animated: true)
    nameTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
}
```

The entire app is made programmatically. I remade the essentials of the project again through Storyboard and ran into the same problem.

**My question is**: is this intended behavior? If not, what can I do about this? Is there a way to suppress this behavior completely?

Thanks in advance for your time and consideration!

Comment: try setting animated: false

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! I should have included this in my post but I've already tried that and unfortunately, it doesn't fix the problem.